# Using the \points with \totalpoints in titled question in the exam class

Tags: exam

I'm trying to create a titled question in which the total number of points is calculated automatically. I've tried the following things and none achieve my objective:

```latex
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

% Option 1: This works but does not do the points => point switch for 1 point
%\titledquestion{ (\totalpoints{} points) {\bf A question}}

% Option 2: It seems like this should work (?) but it gives an error...
%\titledquestion{ (\totalpoints{} \points) {\bf A question}}

% Option 3: This works, but I have to manually add the points of the 
% parts which I want to avoid...
%\titledquestion{{\bf A question}}[1]

% Option 4: This does not work...I get an error.
%\titledquestion{{\bf A question}}[\totalpoints{}]

\thequestiontitle
\begin{parts}
  \part[1]
  First part.
  \part[0]
  Second part. 
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

For option 2 above, I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\points ...up \let \half =\relax \edef \pt@string 
                                                  {\@points }\ifthenelse {\e...
```

while for option 4, I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.17 ...question{{\bf A question}}[\totalpoints{}]
```

Worst case scenario, I can live with bad grammar, but would like to avoid getting calculated point summaries incorrect...

Any help / suggestions greatly appreciated.

(Note that `\totalpoints{} \points` does work with the `\qformat` command, it just does not seem to work with a titled question?)